# Drupal 6: Theming a field in views

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, themes, drupal-views

Basically I want to create a php code in my template (views-view-field--body.tpl.php) that would say the following...

if [body]
   print [node_view]
endif

Comment: Please clarify your question.  Do you mean you want to print the full node if there's any value in the field "body"?

Comment: No I only want to print the (Node: Link) if there is content in the (Node: Body).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I did to do this was download [Views Custom Field](http://drupal.org/project/views_customfield) and then use this code for the value:

```
<?php 
if ($data->node_revisions_body) { 
 echo '<a href="/node/' . $data->nid .'">view</a>';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head and at first look it seems like you are using fields. If it is so, if you look at views-view-field.tpl.php, the comments specify:

```
  Variables available:
  - $view: The view object
  - $field: The field handler object that can process the input
  - $row: The raw SQL result that can be used
  - $output: The processed output that will normally be used.
```

When fetching output from the $row, this construct should be used:
  $data = $row->{$field->field_alias}

thus you could do something like

```
if ($row->{$field->body}) { 
  print $row->{$field->view_node}
}
```

Comment: Why the braces around $field->field_alias?

Comment: I believe this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147937/php-curly-brace-syntax-for-member-variable - will answer your question