# Variablename as $this-> value?

Tags: php, oop, class, variables, foreach

I am currently in the development of my Class in PHP.
I have an array with values in it, and I would like to use the array fieldname as a $this reference. Let me show you what I got:

```
<?php
class Server {    
    private $playlist;
    private $mp3;
    private static $ressourceFolder;
    private static $sudoUser;
```

And in my array it contains:

```
  array(6) {
    ["playlist"]=>
    int(8002)
    ["mp3"]=>
    int(1024)
    ["ressourceFolder"]=>
    bool(true)
    ["sudoUser"]=>
    bool(true)
  }
```

So I would like to use in my foreach something to get the value of the array field into the class global variable, the array fieldname is the same as the variable so this 'should' work, but it doesn't :(

```
foreach($ressourceArray as $ressourceField=>$ressourceValue) {    
    $this->$ressourceField = $ressourceValue;
}
```

I would really appreciate if someone could tell me why this can't work and how to make this 'workable'...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Static variables should be assigned using the `self` keyword

Comment: You're mixing static and instance variables here. That's why it doesn't work. You'll need to separate arrays.

Answer (score 2):

It does work, see [Demo](http://codepad.org/aKc7LL2G):

```
<?php

$array = array("playlist"=> 8002, "mp3"=>1024);

class Mix {
   public function __construct($array) {
    foreach($array as $key => $value) {
        $this->$key = $value;
      }
   }
}

$class = new Mix($array);
var_dump($class);
```

It will assign new public members to the object `$this` based on key/value pairs of the array.

#### Dealing with bad named keys in the array

If the keys contain values that are not valid variable names, it can be non-trivial to access the properties later (`{property-name}`), see [PHP curly brace syntax for member variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147937/php-curly-brace-syntax-for-member-variable).

Casting the array to object before adding will help to prevent fatal errors for those key names that are completely invalid:

```
$object = (object) $array;
# iterate over object instead of array:
foreach($object as $key => $value) {
  $this->$key = $value;
}
```

Those keys are just dropped by the cast.

Comment: Actually it really helped, so it seems it would work, but why not in my code, mhh I will recheck everything, thanks for the proof though!

Comment: @yes123: That's what the OP asked for. You might find the answer simple because you're a real pro coder, but please mind that not all users are that experienced like you and they have questions, too.

Comment: @all I am sorry, it was working but my variable names were bad coded, *shame* haha I am sorry, but I mean maybe somebody else is going to look for some answer like that... thanks

Comment: @Sebasian: There is a trick to deal with that. Before you iterate over the array, cast it to object. I'll add some code to show how.

Answer (score 0):

You may get it working with the magic method `__set` and `__get`. See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php

Answer (score 0):

> And in my array it contains:

What array? That looks like a array dump of an instance of the class.

> into the class global variable

What global class variable? Classes are not variables. Variables may hold references to objects, or class names.

Assuming you want to iterate through the properties of an object, and

```
$ressourceArray = new Server();
```

The code will work as expected.

If the loop is within a class method, then the loop should be....

```
foreach($this as $ressourceField=>$ressourceValue) {    
   $this->$ressourceField = $ressourceValue;
}
```

If you mean that you are trying to initialize the object properties from an array...

```
class Server {
...
function setValues($ressourceArray)
{
   foreach($ressourceArray as $ressourceField=>$ressourceValue) {    
      $this->$ressourceField = $ressourceValue;
   }
}
```

(BTW there's only one 's' in 'resource')