# Curly Braces Notation in PHP

Tags: php, curly-braces

I was reading source of OpenCart and I ran into such expression below. Could someone explain it to me:

```
$quote = $this->{'model_shipping_' . $result['code']}->getQuote($shipping_address);
```

In the statement, there is a weird code part that is
`$this->{'model_shipping_' . $result['code']}`
which has `{}` and I wonder what that is? It looks an object to me but I am not really sure.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Curly braces are used to denote string or variable interpolation in PHP. It allows you to create 'variable functions', which can allow you to call a function without explicitly knowing what it actually is.

Using this, you can create a property on an object almost like you would an array:

```
$property_name = 'foo';
$object->{$property_name} = 'bar';
// same as $object->foo = 'bar';
```

Or you can call one of a set of methods, if you have some sort of REST API class:

```
$allowed_methods = ('get', 'post', 'put', 'delete');
$method = strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']); // eg, 'POST'

if (in_array($method, $allowed_methods)) {
    return $this->{$method}();
    // return $this->post();
}
```

It's also used in strings to more easily identify interpolation, if you want to:

```
$hello = 'Hello';
$result = "{$hello} world";
```

Of course these are simplifications. The purpose of your example code is to run one of a number of functions depending on the value of `$result['code']`.

Comment: Thanks, I've found this explanation very comprehensible and broad.

Comment: In your first example, simply writing `$object->$property_name = 'bar'` would have the exact same effect. I suppose the braces are just necessary when it's a non-trivial expression

Answer (score 10):

The name of the property is computed during runtime from two strings

Say, `$result['code']` is `'abc'`, the accessed property will be

```
$this->model_shipping_abc
```

This is also helpful, if you have *weird* characters in your property or method names.

Otherwise there would be no way to distinguish between the following:

```
class A {
  public $f = 'f';
  public $func = 'uiae';
}

$a = new A();
echo $a->f . 'unc'; // "func"
echo $a->{'f' . 'unc'}; // "uiae"
```

Comment: Why was nobody saying anything? The code as it stood was not working at all (function invocation missing). Fixed now by using vars instead of functions.

Answer (score 4):

> Curly braces are used to explicitly specify the end of a variable
>   name.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1147942/680578

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex

Comment: Bare-link answers are not answers. If you feel that this question duplicates another, flag it for closure. Otherwise, you should elaborate on the links you cite.

Comment: I know the curly braces in strings but the curly braces are not wrapped up with quotation marks in my example.