# PHP syntax error, "unexpected T_VARIABLE" - isQuestion($query)

Tags: php, syntax-error

Code:

```
public function isQuestion($query){

    $questions = $this->getAllQuestions();

    if (count($questions)){
            foreach ($questions as $q){
                if ($this->isQuestion$q($query)){
                    return $this->isQuestion$q($query);
                }
            }
        }

    return false;
}
```

Error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/ai/application/models/question_model.php on line 7

The problem occurs in:

```
if ($this->isQuestion$q($query)){

return $this->isQuestion$q($query);
```

I have some functions like **isQuestion1**, **isQuestion2**, **isQuestion3**, etc... and I call another **function** **getAllQuestions** that will return me all the numbers of the questions in an array like **1,2,3,4,5...**.

Then I use the above code to check if each function is a question based on a query.

Comment: Wrap it in curly brackets `$this->isQuestion{$q}($query)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the following is invalid syntax:

```
if ($this->isQuestion$q($query)){
```

Try this instead:

```
foreach ($questions as $q) {
    if ($result = $this->{'isQuestion' . $q}()) {
        return $result;
    }
}
return false;
```

Comment: The square brackets around `$mehtod` are superfluous and are not needed: http://codepad.org/joagmyXQ - Also an array with foreach you do not need to check count first if you just return early on success. I edited the question for that.

Comment: @hakra I agree on the `if( $result = blah( ) ) { return $result; }` Still, the square brackets I would keep: it becomes *much* more obvious that you're calling a dynamically named function, so I've added it for clarity. Nevertheless, your improvement seems solid.

Comment: Well variable functions are common in PHP - and documented. But they need to start with a `$`. Or you use the square brackets like in the edit now. Variable functions are here just for reference: http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php

Comment: @hakra I'm fully aware of that, but it's `$this->{$method}()` vs `$this->$method()`. Both are equally valid, but I think the first makes it more obvious that a dynamic function is being called. Future me always thanks me. In the end, it's just a matter of style though.

Comment: Yeah and you should keep away stuff you do not need. E.g. for the full dynamic character you could do stuff like `$this->{"$method"}()` (string usage is known, right?! ;) ) and even more. Not a good idea IMHO. But style questions need time to resolve, so I hope to see you in the less is more camp some day ;)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with your method `isQuestion$q`.

The `$` denotes the start of a variable and is confusing the interpreter.

Write it like so:

`isQuestion{$q}`

The curly braces allow you to insert a variable into a string (or anything with string representation). Read [Curly braces in string in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596837/curly-braces-in-string-in-php) for more information.

Comment: The link is about the wrong thing. This is not about double-quoted strings. Unfortunately, this type of usage of the curly brackets (outside of a double-quoted string) is more or less undocumented in the PHP manual. Compare [PHP curly brace syntax for member variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147937/php-curly-brace-syntax-for-member-variable) which gives the wrong link, too. -- [PHP Variable Names: Curly Brace Madness](http://cowburn.info/2008/01/12/php-vars-curly-braces/)

Comment: @hakra Indeed, it is supplementary information because I'm assuming the OP hasn't encountered curly braces yet. I too couldn't find anything in the PHP docs.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to call a function with a dynamic name, have a look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func-array.php or https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php

You might want to ensure that the method really exists in order to avoid getting fatal errors: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php

Also check if you want to replace

```
if ($this->isQuestion$q($query)){
    return $this->isQuestion$q($query);
}
```

with

```
if ($this->isQuestion$q($query)){
    return true;
}
```

In general it might be better to create an `interface` `Question` and hold an `array` with the Question instances to be asked.