# Cannot use object of type stdClass as array while parsing array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array (the response I get from a service upon a POST request)

```
echo count($myarray);
```

gives 2 as result

```
var_dump($myarray);
```

gives

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#31 (12) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["name"]=>
    string(5) "name"
    ["my_numbr"]=>
    string(18) "a:1:{i:0;s:1:"1";}"
    ["total"]=>
    string(7) "s:0:"";"
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#30 (12) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "4"
    ["name"]=>
    string(3) "john"
    ["my_numbr"]=>
    string(18) "a:1:{i:0;s:1:"2";}"
    ["total"]=>
    string(18) "a:1:{i:0;s:1:"2";}" 
  }
}
```

All I am trying to do is print the array using a for loop like this,

```
for($i=0;$i<count($myarray);$i++)
{
  echo $myarray[$i]["name"];
  echo $myarray[$i]["total"];
}
```

But I am getting this error.

Comment: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array @bernlim

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30680938/3933332

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have an array of objects not arrays, try this:

```
foreach ($myarray as $item) {
    echo $item->name;
    echo $item->total;
}
```

Enjoy.