# Return value from game stats on Steam Web Api

Tags: php, arrays, xml, steam-web-api

I'm trying to echo a value from the game stats of a certain CS:GO player using Steam's Web API.

I'm grabbing the file as so:

```
 $gamestatlink = file_get_contents('http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=730&key=<<MY API KEY>>&steamid=<<PLAYERS STEAM ID>>&format=json');
$statarray = json_decode($gamestatlink, true);
```

and attempting to echo the line with

```
echo $statarray['playerstats']['stats'][0]['total_kills'][0];
```

However, the echo returns empty.

The file returns

```
    {
        "playerstats": {
            "steamID": ">",
            "gameName": "ValveTestApp260",
            "stats": [
                {
                    "name": "total_kills",
                    "value": 508
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_deaths",
                    "value": 1100
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_time_played",
                    "value": 106761
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_planted_bombs",
                    "value": 8
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_defused_bombs",
                    "value": 10
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_wins",
                    "value": 558
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_damage_done",
                    "value": 74944
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_money_earned",
                    "value": 3262500
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_kills_knife",
                    "value": 3
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_kills_glock",
                    "value": 13
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_kills_deagle",
                    "value": 2
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_kills_elite",
                    "value": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_kills_fiveseven",
                    "value": 14
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_kills_xm1014",
                    "value": 7
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_kills_ump45",
                    "value": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_kills_p90",
                    "value": 2
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_kills_awp",
                    "value": 4
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_kills_ak47",
                    "value": 11
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_kills_aug",
                    "value": 250
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_kills_famas",
                    "value": 15
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_kills_m249",
                    "value": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_kills_headshot",
                    "value": 199
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_kills_enemy_weapon",
                    "value": 14
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_wins_pistolround",
                    "value": 4
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_wins_map_cs_assault",
                    "value": 3
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_wins_map_de_cbble",
                    "value": 16
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_wins_map_de_dust2",
                    "value": 225
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_wins_map_de_dust",
                    "value": 16
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_wins_map_de_inferno",
                    "value": 123
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_wins_map_de_train",
                    "value": 21
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_weapons_donated",
                    "value": 61
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_broken_windows",
                    "value": 2
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_kills_enemy_blinded",
                    "value": 3
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_kills_knife_fight",
                    "value": 3
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_kills_against_zoomed_sniper",
                    "value": 58
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_shots_hit",
                    "value": 2534
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_shots_fired",
                    "value": 17261
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_rounds_played",
                    "value": 1264
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_shots_deagle",
                    "value": 61
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_shots_glock",
                    "value": 707
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_shots_elite",
                    "value": 74
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_shots_fiveseven",
                    "value": 204
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_shots_awp",
                    "value": 38
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_shots_ak47",
                    "value": 427
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_shots_aug",
                    "value": 6669
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_shots_famas",
                    "value": 868
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_shots_p90",
                    "value": 156
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_shots_ump45",
                    "value": 41
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_shots_xm1014",
                    "value": 624
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_shots_m249",
                    "value": 42
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_hits_deagle",
                    "value": 8
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_hits_glock",
                    "value": 125
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_hits_elite",
                    "value": 15
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_hits_fiveseven",
                    "value": 37
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_hits_awp",
                    "value": 6
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_hits_ak47",
                    "value": 35
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_hits_aug",
                    "value": 1115
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_hits_famas",
                    "value": 77
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_hits_p90",
                    "value": 14
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_hits_ump45",
                    "value": 2
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_hits_xm1014",
                    "value": 90
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_hits_m249",
                    "value": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_rounds_map_cs_assault",
                    "value": 9
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_rounds_map_cs_office",
                    "value": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_rounds_map_de_cbble",
                    "value": 44
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_rounds_map_de_dust2",
                    "value": 523
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_rounds_map_de_dust",
                    "value": 20
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_rounds_map_de_inferno",
                    "value": 256
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_rounds_map_de_train",
                    "value": 61
                },
                {
                    "name": "last_match_t_wins",
                    "value": 8
                },
                {
                    "name": "last_match_ct_wins",
                    "value": 2
                },
                {
                    "name": "last_match_wins",
                    "value": 2
                },
                {
                    "name": "last_match_max_players",
                    "value": 20
                },
                {
                    "name": "last_match_kills",
                    "value": 5
                },
                {
                    "name": "last_match_deaths",
                    "value": 12
                },
                {
                    "name": "last_match_mvps",
                    "value": 0
                },
                {
                    "name": "last_match_favweapon_id",
                    "value": 8
                },
                {
                    "name": "last_match_favweapon_shots",
                    "value": 66
                },
                {
                    "name": "last_match_favweapon_hits",
                    "value": 12
                },
                {
                    "name": "last_match_favweapon_kills",
                    "value": 3
                },
                {
                    "name": "last_match_damage",
                    "value": 637
                },
                {
                    "name": "last_match_money_spent",
                    "value": 29700
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_mvps",
                    "value": 30
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_matches_won",
                    "value": 46
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_matches_played",
                    "value": 113
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_contribution_score",
                    "value": 1083
                },
                {
                    "name": "last_match_contribution_score",
                    "value": 10
                },
                {
                    "name": "last_match_rounds",
                    "value": 10
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_kills_hkp2000",
                    "value": 58
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_shots_hkp2000",
                    "value": 1673
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_hits_hkp2000",
                    "value": 373
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_shots_p250",
                    "value": 16
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_kills_sg556",
                    "value": 64
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_shots_sg556",
                    "value": 1705
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_hits_sg556",
                    "value": 239
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_hits_scar20",
                    "value": 3
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_kills_scar20",
                    "value": 2
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_shots_scar20",
                    "value": 26
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_shots_ssg08",
                    "value": 49
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_hits_ssg08",
                    "value": 8
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_kills_ssg08",
                    "value": 3
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_shots_mp7",
                    "value": 172
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_hits_mp7",
                    "value": 34
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_kills_mp7",
                    "value": 9
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_hits_nova",
                    "value": 262
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_kills_nova",
                    "value": 28
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_shots_nova",
                    "value": 2037
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_hits_negev",
                    "value": 2
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_shots_negev",
                    "value": 91
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_shots_sawedoff",
                    "value": 56
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_shots_bizon",
                    "value": 88
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_hits_bizon",
                    "value": 4
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_kills_tec9",
                    "value": 3
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_shots_tec9",
                    "value": 117
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_hits_tec9",
                    "value": 16
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_shots_mag7",
                    "value": 144
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_hits_mag7",
                    "value": 18
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_kills_m4a1",
                    "value": 10
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_kills_galilar",
                    "value": 7
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_shots_m4a1",
                    "value": 640
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_shots_galilar",
                    "value": 535
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_shots_taser",
                    "value": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_hits_m4a1",
                    "value": 41
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_hits_galilar",
                    "value": 39
                },
                {
                    "name": "total_matches_won_train",
                    "value": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "GI.lesson.csgo_instr_explain_buymenu",
                    "value": 16
                },
                {
                    "name": "GI.lesson.csgo_instr_explain_buyarmor",
                    "value": 16
                },
                {
                    "name": "GI.lesson.csgo_instr_explain_plant_bomb",
                    "value": 16
                },
                {
                    "name": "GI.lesson.csgo_instr_explain_bomb_carrier",
                    "value": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "GI.lesson.bomb_sites_A",
                    "value": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "GI.lesson.defuse_planted_bomb",
                    "value": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "GI.lesson.csgo_instr_explain_follow_bomber",
                    "value": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "GI.lesson.csgo_instr_explain_pickup_bomb",
                    "value": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "GI.lesson.csgo_instr_explain_prevent_bomb_pickup",
                    "value": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "GI.lesson.Csgo_cycle_weapons_kb",
                    "value": 16
                },
                {
                    "name": "GI.lesson.csgo_instr_explain_zoom",
                    "value": 16
                },
                {
                    "name": "GI.lesson.csgo_instr_explain_reload",
                    "value": 17
                },
                {
                    "name": "GI.lesson.tr_explain_plant_bomb",
                    "value": 16
                },
                {
                    "name": "GI.lesson.version_number",
                    "value": 16
                },
                {
                    "name": "GI.lesson.find_planted_bomb",
                    "value": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "GI.lesson.csgo_instr_rescue_zone",
                    "value": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "GI.lesson.csgo_instr_explain_inspect",
                    "value": 32
                }
            ]
            ,
            "achievements": [
                {
                    "name": "WIN_BOMB_PLANT",
                    "achieved": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "KILL_ENEMY_LOW",
                    "achieved": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "KILL_ENEMY_MED",
                    "achieved": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "BOMB_DEFUSE_CLOSE_CALL",
                    "achieved": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "WIN_BOMB_DEFUSE",
                    "achieved": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "WIN_ROUNDS_LOW",
                    "achieved": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "WIN_ROUNDS_MED",
                    "achieved": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "GIVE_DAMAGE_LOW",
                    "achieved": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "GIVE_DAMAGE_MED",
                    "achieved": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "EARN_MONEY_LOW",
                    "achieved": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "EARN_MONEY_MED",
                    "achieved": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "KILL_ENEMY_AUG",
                    "achieved": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "KILL_ENEMY_TEAM",
                    "achieved": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "LAST_PLAYER_ALIVE",
                    "achieved": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "KILL_ENEMY_LAST_BULLET",
                    "achieved": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "DAMAGE_NO_KILL",
                    "achieved": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "KILL_LOW_DAMAGE",
                    "achieved": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "KILL_ENEMY_RELOADING",
                    "achieved": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "KILL_ENEMIES_WHILE_BLIND",
                    "achieved": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "WIN_KNIFE_FIGHTS_LOW",
                    "achieved": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "HIP_SHOT",
                    "achieved": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "KILL_WHEN_AT_LOW_HEALTH",
                    "achieved": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "FAST_ROUND_WIN",
                    "achieved": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "LOSSLESS_EXTERMINATION",
                    "achieved": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "UNSTOPPABLE_FORCE",
                    "achieved": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "IMMOVABLE_OBJECT",
                    "achieved": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "WIN_MAP_DE_DUST2",
                    "achieved": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "WIN_MAP_DE_INFERNO",
                    "achieved": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "KILL_ENEMY_IN_AIR",
                    "achieved": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "KILL_BOMB_PICKUP",
                    "achieved": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "AVENGE_FRIEND",
                    "achieved": 1
                }
            ]

        }
    }
```

I use a similar code to read a player summary file, which is structured slightly differently, but the code works.

I am attempting to grab the `value` of `total_kills`.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I do not feel as though the answer at [How can I access an array/object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680938/how-can-i-access-an-array-object) helps me here, as the structure of the returned array is different, and uses a different api.

Comment: Please show us your array structure

Comment: There is no `total_kills` key in: `$statarray['playerstats']['stats'][0]` nor is there any inner Array from there; What do you want to access ?

Comment: I am attempting to access the value for total_kills

Comment: As I said above, there is no key: `total_kills`, so you can't access an element, which does not exist

Comment: What would be the expected output of your echo statement?

Comment: 508. If total_kills is not a key, then what is

' "stats": [
   {
    "name": "total_kills",
    "value": 508
   }, ' @Rizier123

Comment: ^^ Ah. Then read the **entire** dupe and you will find your answer there.