# How can I access a property with an invalid name?

Tags: php, class, variables, properties, stdclass

I'm adding data to a stdClass object that is going to be sent through a 3rd party API and so the names I am giving to the elements of this object are actually being defined by that external service.

```
$insertArray = array();
$insertArray[0] = new stdclass();
$insertArray[0]->Name = $name;
$insertArray[0]->PhoneNumber = $phone;
```

This was all working wonderfully until I came across a property with an [invalid name](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php):

```
$insertArray[0]->First.Name = $firstname;
```

So that isn't valid PHP syntax, so is there a way around this?

Comment: `$insertArray[0]->{'First.Name'} = $firstname;`

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to the comments (@AbraCadaver), [Complex (curly) syntax](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex) is the way to go for invalid variables or property names:

```
$insertArray[0]->{"First.Name"} = $firstname;
```