# How Get Value from multidimensional array in php

Tags: php, arrays, api, multidimensional-array

I have build an RestAPI to get value from other server to my server i'm getting this value in XML format as given below

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [hotel-id] => XXXXX
    [room-types] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [room-type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [room-id] => XXXXXX
                            [room-name] => XXXXXX
                            [room-status] => XXXXXX
                        )

                    [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [room-id] => XXXXXX
                            [room-name] => XXXXXX
                            [room-status] => XXXXXX
                        )

                )

        )

    [status] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [code] => S002
            [description] => Request Executed Successfully.
        )

)
```

By below mention code i'm try to get value of room-type object

```
$value = (string) $array_data->room-types->room-type;
```

But every time i'm getting this error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR) in on
>   line 27

Someone please help

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33157296/3933332 especially, since you have an invalid variable name as property

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this, because you indexex contains `-` :

```
$array_data->{"room-types"}->{"room-type"}
```

Comment: how to get same value if it is in Json decode

Comment: Could you precise your question ?