# Access element of node of PHP stdClass object

Tags: php

I have a stdClass object of following format as show in figure.
[image]

I want to access NumberOfUnits. I have tried
                                     `$finalbooking->HotelReservations->HotelReservation->RoomStays->RoomStay->RoomTypes{0}->{'@attributes'}->NumberOfUnits;`

and

`$finalbooking->HotelReservations->HotelReservation->RoomStays->RoomStay->RoomTypes->{'@attributes'}->NumberOfUnits;`

but no luck. Any help would be appreciated. Thank You

Comment: For your example also see see the linked ones: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10333200 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/33157296

Comment: Never mind, I made it working. I just forgot to point the '0' object. the solution was `$finalbooking->HotelReservations->HotelReservation->RoomStays->RoomStay->RoomTypes->{'0'}->{'@attributes'}->NumberOfUnits;`