# syntax error, unexpected '.1' (T_DNUMBER), expecting

Tags: php, curl

```
stdClass Object
(
    [availableVariants] => stdClass Object
        (
            [v0.1.0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [resourceName] => demo
                    [post] => 
                    [delete] => 
                    [put] => 
                )
           [v1.1.0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [resourceName] => demo2
                    [post] => 
                    [delete] => 
                    [put] => 
                )
)
)
```

I am get this data with curl and I useing `$data= $catUrl->availableVariants->v1.1.0->resourceName`.

But getting error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.1' (T_DNUMBER), expecting ',' or ';'

Comment: if print_r($catUrl->availableVariants) you getting result

Comment: yes but how to get resourceName

Comment: @anujsharma look at the link  at the top of your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33157296/how-can-i-access-a-property-with-an-invalid-name

Comment: It's working now thanks