# "syntax error, unexpected '/', expecting..." in stdClass Objects in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, stdclass

I am using [abraham's twitteroauth](https://twitteroauth.com/) and I want to get

```
$limits->resources->account->/account/verify_credentials->remaining;
```

from **stdClass Objects** and I have this error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '/', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in...

Problem is "/" at "/account/verify_credentials", but I cannot change Twitter API's JSON data.

How can call this data **without** using [objectToArray function](http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2009/php-tip-convert-stdclass-object-to-multidimensional-array-and-convert-multidimensional-array-to-stdclass-object/)?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33157296/3933332

Comment: Thanks @Rizier123. I solved the problem with:
`$limits->resources->account->{'/account/verify_credentials'}->remaining`