# PHP : How to access Object inside Object with weird "Key" name?

Tags: php, json, object

I have a JSON Object returned from the remote Web Service (via Curl call). The Object is something like this:

```
stdClass Object ( [https://example.com] => stdClass Object ( [hash] => 8 [id] => 277 ) )
```

How am i suppose to access the values like: `hash`, `id` from this Object please?

I tried:

```
$Object = json_decode( $curl_return );

echo $Object->hash; // Didn't work!
echo $Object[0]->hash; // Didn't work!
echo $Object[0]['hash']; // Didn't work!
echo $Object['https://example.com']->hash; // Didn't work!
```

Please kindly help.

Comment: Also make sure not to overlook: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33157296/3933332 since you got an invalid property name here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work:

```
$url = 'https://example.com';

echo $Object->$url->hash;
```

Alternatively you can decode the JSON to an associative array instead of a `\stdClass` by setting the second argument to `true` with:

```
json_decode($json, true);
```

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 1):

Pass `TRUE` as the second argument to [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) and it returns arrays, not objects.

All you have to do then is to access the values using the usual [array access](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php#language.types.array.syntax.accessing) syntax, with square brackets:

```
echo($Object['https://example.com']['hash']);
```