# Make array from String

Tags: php, arrays

I'm trying to do it in array view. I was try like this but not success.

```
$AllData = "Name=John&Title=CEO&Comment=nothing";
print_r($AllData);
// also want to echo only Name or only Comments.
```

May will get a solution soon. Thanks in advance

Comment: The PHP function explode() would be the best way of accomplishing this.

Comment: Can you please send me the original URL. where you seen that it's already solved please?

Comment: And see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30680938/3933332 when you have trouble accessing a single array element

Comment: How you can call it similar ?
There is my question ok?
$AllData = "Name=John&Title=CEO&Comment=nothing";
From there i want to echo only Name. so how is it possible, can you simple reply here?

Comment: 1) See the duplicate how you can turn your query string into an array 2) And if you then have trouble accessing a particular array element see the link post above