# how to get json value with php

Tags: php, json

Here parameters of API respond :

```
{"cod":"200","message":0.0045,
"city":{"id":1851632,"name":"Shuzenji",
"coord":{"lon":138.933334,"lat":34.966671},
"country":"JP"},
"cnt":38,
"list":[{
        "dt":1406106000,
        "main":{
            "temp":298.77,
            "temp_min":298.77,
            "temp_max":298.774,
            "pressure":1005.93,
            "sea_level":1018.18,
            "grnd_level":1005.93,
            "humidity":87},
        "weather":[{"id":804,"main":"Clouds","description":"overcast clouds","icon":"04d"}],
        "clouds":{"all":88},
        "wind":{"speed":5.71,"deg":229.501},
        "sys":{"pod":"d"},
        "dt_txt":"2014-07-23 09:00:00"}
        ]}
```

I can't get value "Overcast" with my php code :

```
   echo $data['list'][0]['weather']['description'];
   echo $data['list'][1]['weather']['description'];
```

...

I tried several combinaison, i read this article 
[How do I extract data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-do-i-extract-data-from-json-with-php)

But nothing work...

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30680938/3933332

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like 'weather' is an array.

Try `$data['list'][0]['weather'][0]['description'];`

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure you have decoded the json.

```
$decodedData = json_decode($data);
```

Then, try accessing the object's properties and arrays like this:

```
echo $decodedData->list[0]->weather[0]->description;
```