# How to extract from multi dimensional array using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

How to extract this multi dimensional array from php. I am using `codeigniter`  framework.

```
   array(2) {
    [0] => array(14)
    {
    ["Key"] => 
      string(48) "32;FaXmBQJ7/0MATwBVAFAAMAAxADIAOA==9;1261414580;"
      ["Type"] => string(12) "Store_Coupon"
      ["Code"] => string(8) "COUP0128"
      ["Coupon_Issuer"] => string(2) "11"
      ["Coupon_Reference_No"] => string(1) "1"
      ["Description"] => string(5) "test2"
      ["Price_Group"] => string(3) "ALL"
      ["Discount_Type"] => string(15) "Discount_Amount"
      ["Discount_Value"] => string(1) "0"
      ["Validation_Period_ID"] => string(2) "14"
      ["Validation_Description"] => string(15) "2016 membership"
      ["Starting_Date"] => string(10) "2016-01-01"
      ["Ending_Date"] => string(10) "2016-12-31"
      ["Status"] => string(8) "Disabled"
    }

  [1] => array(14)
    {
    ["Key"] => string(48) "32;FaXmBQJ7/0MATwBVAFAATwBOADAAMg==9;1261413680;"
    ["Type"] => string(12) "Store_Coupon"
    ["Code"] => string(8) "COUPON02"
    ["Coupon_Issuer"] => string(2) "11"
    ["Coupon_Reference_No"] => string(1) "2"
    ["Description"] => string(6) "test 3"
    ["Price_Group"] => string(3) "ALL"
    ["Discount_Type"] => string(16) "Discount_Percent"
    ["Discount_Value"] => string(1) "0"
    ["Validation_Period_ID"] => string(2) "14"
    ["Validation_Description"] => string(15) "2016 membership"
    ["Starting_Date"] => string(10) "2016-01-01"
    ["Ending_Date"] => string(10) "2016-12-31"["Status"] => string(8) "Disabled"
    }
}
```

I want to extract `Coupon_Reference_No` element. Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access an array/object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680938/how-can-i-access-an-array-object)

Answer (score 1):

Just do a foreach and store that variable in an array. Supposing your aray is $array

```
$Coupon_Reference_No = array();
foreach($array as $key=>$value){
 if($key == 'Coupon_Reference_No'){
   $Coupon_Reference_No[] = $value;
 }
}
```

You will get an array $Coupon_Reference_No as array("1","2")

Comment: Hi @Amit Ray Thanks for the answer. I will try this.  i try array_column($result, 'Coupon_Reference_No'); much simpler Thank you