# Array lose keys after second foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, key

What I use:

```
$raw = file_get_contents('url');
$raw = json_decode($raw,true);

foreach($raw['data'] as $spell){
  var_dump($spell);
}
```

What I get:

```
array(1) {
    ["image"]=> array(2){
        ["w"]=> int(48)
        ["h"]=> int(48)
    }
}
```

For now everything is fine.

But when I use a second loop (because of more than 1 keys & values) like this:

```
foreach ($raw['data'] as $spell){
    foreach ($spell['image'] as $image) {
        var_dump($image);
    }
}
```

I get:

```
int(48) int(48)
```

Nothing else.
I expected to get:

```
array(2){
    ["w"]=> int(48)
    ["h"]=> int(48)
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: With the second foreach loop you go through the subArray `$raw["data"]["image"]` which only contain integer values and not arrays, so it prints those. Change the second foreach loop to: `foreach ($spell['image'] as $key => $image) echo "$key => $value \n";` Then you see your key. If you want your expected output you just want: `var_dump($raw["data"]["image"]);`

Comment: Had to read your answer three times, but now I got it and it works. Thanks so much :)

Comment: But, how can I get them by the `['w']` and `['h']`, I need to print them multiple times out.

Comment: If you want to access them directly see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/30680938/3933332

Comment: Got it! I just needed one loop with `foreach ($raw['data'] as $spell)` and `print $spell['image']['x'];` in it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> With the second foreach loop you go through the subArray
>   `$raw["data"]["image"]` which only contain integer values and not
>   arrays, so it prints those. Change the second foreach loop to:
>   `foreach ($spell['image'] as $key => $image) echo "$key => $value
>   \n";` Then you see your key.

I used

```
foreach ($raw['data'] as $spell){
    print $spell['image']['x'];
}
```

Thanks to Rizier123 for the answer!