# How to get specific entry from JSON file in PHP

Tags: php, json

I have [this site's](https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/) output which gives me the value of 750+ altcoins.

I get the output, and decode it as `$data`.

Let's simplify it to:

```
[
    {
        "id": "bitcoin", 
        "name": "Bitcoin", 
        "symbol": "BTC", 
        "rank": "1", 
        "price_usd": "610.561", 
        "price_btc": "1.0", 
        "24h_volume_usd": "44104400.0", 
        "market_cap_usd": "9688885050.0", 
        "available_supply": "15868824.0", 
        "total_supply": "15868824.0", 
        "percent_change_1h": "0.12", 
        "percent_change_24h": "0.25", 
        "percent_change_7d": "-1.61", 
        "last_updated": "1473929966"
    }, 
    {
        "id": "ethereum", 
        "name": "Ethereum", 
        "symbol": "ETH", 
        "rank": "2", 
        "price_usd": "12.0793", 
        "price_btc": "0.0197864", 
        "24h_volume_usd": "8171040.0", 
        "market_cap_usd": "1014555388.0", 
        "available_supply": "83991240.0", 
        "total_supply": "83991240.0", 
        "percent_change_1h": "0.21", 
        "percent_change_24h": "1.25", 
        "percent_change_7d": "4.92", 
        "last_updated": "1473929962"
    }, 
    {
        "id": "ripple", 
        "name": "Ripple", 
        "symbol": "XRP", 
        "rank": "3", 
        "price_usd": "0.00597615", 
        "price_btc": "0.00000979", 
        "24h_volume_usd": "1017240.0", 
        "market_cap_usd": "211062429.0", 
        "available_supply": "35317458440.0", 
        "total_supply": "99997205581.0", 
        "percent_change_1h": "-0.16", 
        "percent_change_24h": "1.53", 
        "percent_change_7d": "0.88", 
        "last_updated": "1473929942"
    }, 
    {
        "id": "litecoin", 
        "name": "Litecoin", 
        "symbol": "LTC", 
        "rank": "4", 
        "price_usd": "3.83018", 
        "price_btc": "0.00627398", 
        "24h_volume_usd": "1101600.0", 
        "market_cap_usd": "182184060.0", 
        "available_supply": "47565404.0", 
        "total_supply": "47565404.0", 
        "percent_change_1h": "-0.11", 
        "percent_change_24h": "0.14", 
        "percent_change_7d": "-3.61", 
        "last_updated": "1473929943"
    }, 
    {
        "id": "monero", 
        "name": "Monero", 
        "symbol": "XMR", 
        "rank": "5", 
        "price_usd": "10.4646", 
        "price_btc": "0.0171415", 
        "24h_volume_usd": "4920040.0", 
        "market_cap_usd": "134987751.0", 
        "available_supply": "12899466.0", 
        "total_supply": "12899466.0", 
        "percent_change_1h": "-0.35", 
        "percent_change_24h": "-2.47", 
        "percent_change_7d": "-14.04", 
        "last_updated": "1473929949"
    }, 
]
```

How do I get the `price_usd` of let's say, ripple? I know that I can do `$data[3]['price_usd']`, however the info is based on the rank. The rank changes. How do I get it to retrieve the value of ripple without using `[1]`? I've tried `$data['bitcoin']['price_usd']`, but to no avail.

I've searched stackexchange for answers on this, but people have only told me what I know so far. Not how to find the value of a specific entry.

Regards

Comment: Quick answer. With a loop.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access an array/object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680938/how-can-i-access-an-array-object)

Comment: Don't see how this is a duplicate. That question is asking information which I already have stated is not what I want, "I've tried $data['bitcoin']['price_usd'], but to no avail."

Comment: @WhytetheWeeabear First, your question boils down to a basic understanding of how to access array/object values in PHP. Second, `$data['bitcoin']['price_usd']` **clearly** wouldn't yield any expectation of a value in this data, since there is no `bitcoin` key anywhere in this JSON. Read the manual to learn how to use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json-decode), understand the differences between [Arrays](http://php.net/language.types.array) and [Objects](http://php.net/language.types.object) in PHP and try spending a little more time debugging your code.

Comment: This is why I am asking for help. The JSON in your thread that you suggested is in a different format.

Answer (score 2):

```
$price = null;
foreach ($data as $item) {
    if ($item["id"] == "bitcoin") {
        $price = $item["price_usd"];
        break;
    }
}

var_dump($price);
```

Comment: @Whyte the Weeabear, as you mentioned that you want only required coins from the json. So above code will not optimal, which it needs to visit the json every time for new coin mentioned in array.

Answer (score 1):

suppose say you have list of needed coins mentioned in array which is any sequence of the json sequence. Then instead of checking the whole json data for each time. I have checked that if any `id` from array matched with the json `id` then select the `price_usd`. This will have the optimal results by just traversing the json once.

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/');
$data = json_decode($data, true);
$need = array(
    'nexus',
    'bitcoin',
    'zombiecoin',
    'ambercoin'
);
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if (in_array($data[$key]['id'], $need)) {
        echo $data[$key]['id'] . " = " . $data[$key]['price_usd'];
        echo "<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

**Results -**

```
bitcoin = 610.398
nexus = 0.0356638
ambercoin = 0.0104771
zombiecoin = 0.000121343
```

Comment: This works, but however I want to be able to define and save a certain coin's value as a variable.

Comment: lets say you defined a certain coins in array. so you want their values from json.?

Comment: Yes. Let's say I want values for Bitcoin, Ethereum and Ripple. How will I do this?

Comment: What is did is - by only one traverse i have checked the needed coins mentioned earlier with the possibility of mentioned coins in the array can be any order irrespective of JSON sequence

Comment: Love your solution. However I want the loop to save the coin values as their own variables. Can't see a way of doing that here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123423/discussion-between-rohan-khude-and-whyte-the-weeabear).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like this:

```
function getPrice($data, $id) {
   $price = 0;

   foreach($data as $item) {
      if($item->id == $id) {
          $price = $item->price_usd;
      }
   }

   return $price;
}
```

And then you can use it for ripple case like this.

```
$dribblePrice = getPrice($data, 'ripple');
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/ubuntu/workspace/calculated.php

Answer (score 0):

Use my customized function to generate a associative array,

```
function getAssociativeArray($result,$keyfield="") {
            $dataarray = array();
            $i=0;
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                if($keyfield!="") $dataarray[$row[$keyfield]] = $row;
                else $dataarray[$i] = $row;
                $i++;
            }
            return $dataarray;
        }
```

Pass the `$data` array and the Keyfield as id

```
$data = getAssociativeArray($data,'id');
```

then you can access the result as `$data['bitcoin']['price_usd']` without worrying about the rank of the element.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it :

```
$data = json_decode('[
    {
        "id": "bitcoin", 
        "name": "Bitcoin", 
        "symbol": "BTC", 
        "rank": "1", 
        "price_usd": "610.561", 
        "price_btc": "1.0", 
        "24h_volume_usd": "44104400.0", 
        "market_cap_usd": "9688885050.0", 
        "available_supply": "15868824.0", 
        "total_supply": "15868824.0", 
        "percent_change_1h": "0.12", 
        "percent_change_24h": "0.25", 
        "percent_change_7d": "-1.61", 
        "last_updated": "1473929966"
    }, 
    {
        "id": "ethereum", 
        "name": "Ethereum", 
        "symbol": "ETH", 
        "rank": "2", 
        "price_usd": "12.0793", 
        "price_btc": "0.0197864", 
        "24h_volume_usd": "8171040.0", 
        "market_cap_usd": "1014555388.0", 
        "available_supply": "83991240.0", 
        "total_supply": "83991240.0", 
        "percent_change_1h": "0.21", 
        "percent_change_24h": "1.25", 
        "percent_change_7d": "4.92", 
        "last_updated": "1473929962"
    }, 
    {
        "id": "ripple", 
        "name": "Ripple", 
        "symbol": "XRP", 
        "rank": "3", 
        "price_usd": "0.00597615", 
        "price_btc": "0.00000979", 
        "24h_volume_usd": "1017240.0", 
        "market_cap_usd": "211062429.0", 
        "available_supply": "35317458440.0", 
        "total_supply": "99997205581.0", 
        "percent_change_1h": "-0.16", 
        "percent_change_24h": "1.53", 
        "percent_change_7d": "0.88", 
        "last_updated": "1473929942"
    }, 
    {
        "id": "litecoin", 
        "name": "Litecoin", 
        "symbol": "LTC", 
        "rank": "4", 
        "price_usd": "3.83018", 
        "price_btc": "0.00627398", 
        "24h_volume_usd": "1101600.0", 
        "market_cap_usd": "182184060.0", 
        "available_supply": "47565404.0", 
        "total_supply": "47565404.0", 
        "percent_change_1h": "-0.11", 
        "percent_change_24h": "0.14", 
        "percent_change_7d": "-3.61", 
        "last_updated": "1473929943"
    }, 
    {
        "id": "monero", 
        "name": "Monero", 
        "symbol": "XMR", 
        "rank": "5", 
        "price_usd": "10.4646", 
        "price_btc": "0.0171415", 
        "24h_volume_usd": "4920040.0", 
        "market_cap_usd": "134987751.0", 
        "available_supply": "12899466.0", 
        "total_supply": "12899466.0", 
        "percent_change_1h": "-0.35", 
        "percent_change_24h": "-2.47", 
        "percent_change_7d": "-14.04", 
        "last_updated": "1473929949"
    }
]');

foreach ($data as $item) {
    if($item->id === 'ripple'){
      echo $item->price_usd;
      break;
    }
}
```

Note that you need to remove the trailing comma from the last item for json_decode to work.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
 $json='[
                {
                    "id": "bitcoin", 
                    "name": "Bitcoin", 
                    "symbol": "BTC", 
                    "rank": "1", 
                    "price_usd": "610.561", 
                    "price_btc": "1.0", 
                    "24h_volume_usd": "44104400.0", 
                    "market_cap_usd": "9688885050.0", 
                    "available_supply": "15868824.0", 
                    "total_supply": "15868824.0", 
                    "percent_change_1h": "0.12", 
                    "percent_change_24h": "0.25", 
                    "percent_change_7d": "-1.61", 
                    "last_updated": "1473929966"
                }, 
                {
                    "id": "ethereum", 
                    "name": "Ethereum", 
                    "symbol": "ETH", 
                    "rank": "2", 
                    "price_usd": "12.0793", 
                    "price_btc": "0.0197864", 
                    "24h_volume_usd": "8171040.0", 
                    "market_cap_usd": "1014555388.0", 
                    "available_supply": "83991240.0", 
                    "total_supply": "83991240.0", 
                    "percent_change_1h": "0.21", 
                    "percent_change_24h": "1.25", 
                    "percent_change_7d": "4.92", 
                    "last_updated": "1473929962"
                }, 
                {
                    "id": "ripple", 
                    "name": "Ripple", 
                    "symbol": "XRP", 
                    "rank": "3", 
                    "price_usd": "0.00597615", 
                    "price_btc": "0.00000979", 
                    "24h_volume_usd": "1017240.0", 
                    "market_cap_usd": "211062429.0", 
                    "available_supply": "35317458440.0", 
                    "total_supply": "99997205581.0", 
                    "percent_change_1h": "-0.16", 
                    "percent_change_24h": "1.53", 
                    "percent_change_7d": "0.88", 
                    "last_updated": "1473929942"
                }, 
                {
                    "id": "litecoin", 
                    "name": "Litecoin", 
                    "symbol": "LTC", 
                    "rank": "4", 
                    "price_usd": "3.83018", 
                    "price_btc": "0.00627398", 
                    "24h_volume_usd": "1101600.0", 
                    "market_cap_usd": "182184060.0", 
                    "available_supply": "47565404.0", 
                    "total_supply": "47565404.0", 
                    "percent_change_1h": "-0.11", 
                    "percent_change_24h": "0.14", 
                    "percent_change_7d": "-3.61", 
                    "last_updated": "1473929943"
                }, 
                {
                    "id": "monero", 
                    "name": "Monero", 
                    "symbol": "XMR", 
                    "rank": "5", 
                    "price_usd": "10.4646", 
                    "price_btc": "0.0171415", 
                    "24h_volume_usd": "4920040.0", 
                    "market_cap_usd": "134987751.0", 
                    "available_supply": "12899466.0", 
                    "total_supply": "12899466.0", 
                    "percent_change_1h": "-0.35", 
                    "percent_change_24h": "-2.47", 
                    "percent_change_7d": "-14.04", 
                    "last_updated": "1473929949"
                } 
            ]';
            $var=json_decode($json);
            foreach ($var as $value) {
               if($value->id=='ripple')
               {
                 echo $value->price_usd;
               }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use combination of [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) and [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to get the result.

**Note:** `array_column` is only from **PHP 5.5** onwards.

```
$data = json_decode($json_string, true);
// finding the key of ripple
$key = array_search('ripple', array_column($data, 'id'));
echo $result[$key]['price_usd'];
```

Full Code: (Trimmed JSON string)

```
<?php

$str = '[
    {
        "id": "bitcoin", 
        "name": "Bitcoin", 
        "symbol": "BTC", 
        "rank": "1", 
        "price_usd": "610.471", 
        "price_btc": "1.0", 
        "24h_volume_usd": "44349800.0", 
        "market_cap_usd": "9687471507.0", 
        "available_supply": "15868848.0", 
        "total_supply": "15868848.0", 
        "percent_change_1h": "0.02", 
        "percent_change_24h": "0.19", 
        "percent_change_7d": "-1.74", 
        "last_updated": "1473931166"
    }, 
    {
        "id": "ethereum", 
        "name": "Ethereum", 
        "symbol": "ETH", 
        "rank": "2", 
        "price_usd": "12.0771", 
        "price_btc": "0.0197825", 
        "24h_volume_usd": "8286810.0", 
        "market_cap_usd": "1014377525.0", 
        "available_supply": "83991813.0", 
        "total_supply": "83991813.0", 
        "percent_change_1h": "-0.02", 
        "percent_change_24h": "1.19", 
        "percent_change_7d": "5.02", 
        "last_updated": "1473931161"
    }, 
    {
        "id": "ripple", 
        "name": "Ripple", 
        "symbol": "XRP", 
        "rank": "3", 
        "price_usd": "0.0059753", 
        "price_btc": "0.00000979", 
        "24h_volume_usd": "1018920.0", 
        "market_cap_usd": "211032409.0", 
        "available_supply": "35317458440.0", 
        "total_supply": "99997205581.0", 
        "percent_change_1h": "-0.26", 
        "percent_change_24h": "1.51", 
        "percent_change_7d": "0.86", 
        "last_updated": "1473931142"
    }
]';

$result = json_decode($str, true);

$key = array_search('ripple', array_column($result, 'id'));
echo $result[$key]['price_usd'];
?>
```

Output:

```
0.0059753
```

Comment: process of $data[3]['price_usd']  is same as your answer, then so why could use this lengthy code?

Comment: Because this is using a ranking system. The order of entries change. I tried this code, but it gave me a blank page. I am using PHP 5.5.9-1.

Comment: @WhytetheWeeabear updated the working solution. `$key` will be key(ranking) for ripple in array.

Comment: @RasaMohamed It's not same, `$key` is variable is you haven't noticed.

Answer (score 0):

Since your JSON data is an array of arrays, you could check first if you sub-array has the id 'ripple', and then getting the 'price_usd' like following :

```
function get_usd_price($data) {
    $price_usd = 0.00;

    foreach( $data as $row ) {
        $id = $row['id'];

        if( $id == 'ripple' && array_key_exists('price_usd', $row) ) {
            $price_usd = $row['price_usd'];
        }
    }

    return $price_usd;
}

$data       =   json_decode($myJSONarray);
$price_usd =    get_usd_price('ripple', $data); // returns 0.00597615 in your example
```