# How do I sort a 3-dimensional array that includes objects?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, sorting, multidimensional-array

I'm building a WordPress site where I need to sort the results of a WP_User_Query AFTER the query has already been run. For those of you not familiar, it has elements that look like this:

```
Array (
  [0] => WP_User Object (
    [data] => stdClass Object (
      [ID] => 1
      [user_login] => MarvinLazer
      [user_pass] => $P$BUGHRCjMzlvn7dlGp53UTPC8GMF081/
      [user_nicename] => marvinlazer
      [user_email] => marvin@lazer.com
      [user_url] => http://marvinlazer.com
      [user_registered] => 2017-03-04 23:08:08
      [user_activation_key] =>
      [user_status] => 0
      [display_name] => Marvin Lazer
    )
    [ID] => 1
    [caps] => Array (
      [subscriber] => 1
    )
    [cap_key] => wp_capabilities
    [roles] => Array (
      [0] => subscriber
    )
    [allcaps] => Array (
      [read] => 1
      [level_0] => 1
      [subscriber] => 1
    )
    [filter] =>
  )
  [1] => WP_User Object ( etc. etc.
```

Based on [this very helpful page on PHP array sorting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php/17364128#17364128), I feel like I got something kinda close. Unfortunately, it's just giving me a blank page after the part where the code appears.

```
          function cmp(array $a, array $b) {
              if ($a['data']['display_name'] < $b['data']['display_name']) {
                  return -1;
              } else if ($a['data']['display_name'] > $b['data']['display_name']) {
                  return 1;
              } else {
                  return 0;
              }
          }

          usort($user_query->results, 'cmp');
```

Anyone wanna point me towards what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: [access array/object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30681087/6521116)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are trying to access property of object in method of accessing array element. You cannot use the index to access the property of object. You should use `->` instead of `[]`. You can check this [demo](https://eval.in/803874) to issustrate how to access object property.

refer to [how to access array/object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30681087/6521116)

change your `$a['data']['display_name']` to `$a->data->display_name`, and your `$b` in the compare funciton.

Comment: Didn't work, but I feel like this gets me a step closer! Thank you!

Comment: You can log the variable, and debug it.