# Stuck in echoing data out of variable CodeIgniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, error-handling, php-7

I try to get some information out of my database to my webpage. Everything seems to be fine but there is one thing that doesn't want to go right. I put all my information out my database into $data. When i do this

```
print_r($data);
```

My webpage gives me this:

```
(
[0] => stdClass Object
   (
   [reparatie_id] => 19
   [customer_id] => 4
   [medewerker] => 4
   [name] => Joost
   )
)
```

Everything seems to be good but when i try to do this:

```
echo $data->voornaam;
```

I keep getting this error

```
A PHP Error was encountered


Severity: Notice

Message:  Trying to get property of non-object

Filename: reparaties/cases.php

Line Number: 7

Backtrace:

        File: C:\Ampps\www\beco\application\views\reparaties\cases.php

        Line: 7

        Function: _error_handler            


        File: C:\Ampps\www\beco\application\controllers\Reparaties.php

        Line: 57

        Function: view          


        File: C:\Ampps\www\beco\public\index.php

        Line: 315

        Function: require_once
```

Comment: I don't see `voornaam` property on your given data example? Also, it seems that your `$data` is an `array`, try doing `$data[0]->customer_id`?

Comment: `echo $data->voornaam;` need to be `echo $data[0]->name;` because no `voornaam` property is there in printed result

Comment: @Giedrius Thanx! You realy helped me out. I did not copied the whole output, thats the reason you didn't see 'voornaam'

Comment: @JTempelman glad your issue is solved. `Alive to Die` has posted answer with same idea, can you please accept it as the answer to close this issue.

Comment: best answer of your question is here. [how-can-i-access-an-array-object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680938/how-can-i-access-an-array-object)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `$data` is a single-dimensional-array,so it need to be-

```
$data[0]->reparatie_id;
$data[0]->customer_id;
$data[0]->medewerker;
$data[0]->name;//so on for other indexes
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Actually the $data array has an object at 0 position. So you need to any property of object. do like this:
<?php
$data[0]->reparatie_id;
$data[0]->customer_id;
$data[0]->medewerker;
$data[0]->name; ?>
output will be:
19, 4, 4, joost
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your `$data` array does not have the `voornaam` element in it. So, assuming you want to echo out the elements that are inside the array, you would use the `foreach` array, like this:

```
foreach($data as $value) {
    echo $value->name;
    echo $value->voorname; //if it exists
}
```

But, if you just want to access that single element from the array then you would do this:

```
echo $data[0]->name;
```