# How to access stdClass object of nested array in PHP

Tags: php

I have php array like

```
Array 
( 
[0] => stdClass Object 
    ( [type] => MILESTONE
      [creator] => xyz 
      [tpid] => abc 
      [docname] => STS 
      [items] => stdClass Object 
        ( 
            [MILESTONE_CODE] => ARPOD 
            [MILESTONE_TYPE] => ACT 
            [MILESTONE_DESCRIPTION] => Arrival at Port of Discharge 
            [TRIGGER_EVENT] => Y [ENVIRONMENT] => T 
        ) 
    ) 
[1] => stdClass Object 
    ( 
        [type] => MILESTONE 
        [creator] => xyz 
        [tpid] => abc 
        [docname] => STS 
        [items] => stdClass Object 
        ( 
            [MILESTONE_CODE] => BKD 
            [MILESTONE_TYPE] => EST 
            [MILESTONE_DESCRIPTION] => Booking created 
            [TRIGGER_EVENT] => N 
            [ENVIRONMENT] => P 
        ) 
    ) 
)
```

There are 2 php files written

File 1: In this file I am decoding my json data and got above array

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

 // print_r($data);exit;

foreach ($data as $value){

$TP->createTPConfig($data);  // Here I am calling method for each index of array
}
```

File 2: In this file I have written method to insert data into oracle database.

```
function createTPConfig($dataToBeInsert){

// print_r($dataToBeInsert);exit; // till here I am getting above array

// written insert query here 

}
```

Now in File 2, I want to access array values of

`[type]`, `[creator]`, `[tpid]`, `[docname]`

and again

I want to `foreach(repeat)` loop for `[items]`

and want to access keys and values of

`[MILESTONE_CODE]`, `[MILESTONE_TYPE]`, `[MILESTONE_DESCRIPTION]` and `[TRIGGER_EVENT]`

and insert both keys and values into database

Can anyone help ... your help would be appreciated!

Comment: @deceze, below code worked for me and this kind of scenario I could not find on stackoverflow  

File 1:
   
     $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);  
       if($data != null){
           $TP->createTPConfig($data);
       }

File 2:

      function createTPConfig($dataToBeInsert){

          for ($x=0;$x<count($dataToBeInsert);$x++){ 
    print_r($dataToBeInsert[$x]['items']['MILESTONE_CODE']);
     print_r($dataToBeInsert[$x]['type']);

     foreach($dataToBeInsert[$x]['items'] as $key => $value){
       print_r($key . $value);
          }
      }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

to

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
```

This will give you a full-fledged array. Obligatory man link: [json decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)

Comment: Thanks rndus2r ... I have done changes in my file 1 and now I am able to print same array (posted at beginning) in file 2 if I write 

print_r($dataToBeInsert);exit;

Comment: So your question is cleared?

Comment: No, I am not able to access array elements in file 2

Comment: What does `var_dump($dataToBeInsert[0][items])` result in?

Comment: var_dump($dataToBeInsert[0]['items']);     this does result below

[items] => stdClass Object 
        ( 
            [MILESTONE_CODE] => ARPOD 
            [MILESTONE_TYPE] => ACT 
            [MILESTONE_DESCRIPTION] => Arrival at Port of Discharge 
            [TRIGGER_EVENT] => Y [ENVIRONMENT] => T 
        )

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680938/how-can-i-access-an-array-object