# Cannot pull value out using json_decode

Tags: php, json

For some reason I am not getting the expected output from json_decode. The JSON string comes back from an API call and the first part of the string looks as follows:

```
{"droplets":[{"id":67892618,"name":"NEW-TEK","memory":8192,"vcpus":4,"disk":20,blah blah blah
```

Here is the relevant portion of the code I am using:

```
function Test() {
    $ch = curl_init('https://api.digitalocean.com/v2/droplets?tag_name=MYTAG');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization: Bearer MYTOKEN','Content-Type: application/json'));
    $json = curl_exec($ch);
    $obj = json_decode($json,true);
    echo 'Just making sure everything is working up till here!';
    echo "\n\n";
    $id = $obj->{'id'};
    echo 'Droplet ID: ';
    echo $id;
    exit;
}
```

Ignore all the random echo lines and new line stuff. Just making the example easy to read. As you can see, nothing is getting pulled out of the array and echoed.

[image]

Comment: `$obj = json_decode($json,true);` this gives you an array, not an object

Comment: That's what I was expecting. I wanted to pull the id out of the array. I just named the variable obj.

Comment: Not according to your code.  You're accessing it as if it's an object (and referring to a variable called `$obj`, implying you think it is an object)

Comment: Yeah I just was not experienced enough to know what I was doing... Physicist here, not a programmer :(

Comment: Also possible dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680938/how-can-i-access-an-array-object since OP claimed to know an array was being returned

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using `$obj = json_decode($json,true);` the `true` makes the output  an array, not an object which you try to use here `$id = $obj->{'id'};` Here is what the array looks like:

```
Array
(
    [droplets] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 67892618
                    [name] => NEW-TEK
                    [memory] => 8192
                    [vcpus] => 4
                    [disk] => 20
                )

        )

)
```

Instead use `$id = $obj['droplets'][0]['id'];` as you have to identify the segment of the array you want to look at.

Comment: No luck here. Missing 0?

Comment: $id = $obj['droplets'][0]['id]

Comment: I'm sure this must be a dupe of _something_, no?

Comment: @PatrickQ heh, yeah same goes for 90% of the questions these past few years lol!

Comment: That did it! Thank you! Finally have a working solution!