# If I make POST not working. Error Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, json, foreach, shell-exec

I get following error:

```
Error Notice: Trying to get property of non-object
```

But it works if I remove the POST tag `if (isset($_POST['curlPost'])) {`

```
if (isset($_POST['curlPost'])) {
    $output = shell_exec('curl -X GET ...');
    $goster = json_decode($output);
    foreach ($goster as $gos) {
        echo $gos->value."<br>";
        echo $gos->editable."<br>";
    }
}
```

> Trying to get property of non-object

JSON Response:

```
{
  "success": true,
  "errors": [
    {}
  ],
  "messages": [
    {}
  ],
  "result": {
    "id": "always_online",
    "value": "on",
    "editable": true,
    "modified_on": "2014-01-01T05:20:00.12345Z"
  }
}
```

what is the error?

Comment: What does the JSON in `$output` look like?

Comment: @FabianLauer I updated my question. You can see now

Comment: Looks to me like you're trying to iterate over a non-array.

Comment: You're treating all keys in your json response as objects. Only `result` is actually an object. You're json doesn't seem to need to be iterated over at all. Just do: `$goster->result->value` and `$goster->result->editable`.

Comment: This is a duplicate of [How can I access an array/object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680938/how-can-i-access-an-array-object)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson , Yes. Right now it's worked. Thank you for your time.