# php associated array error

Tags: php, arrays

I write a program in PHP and now I learn assosiated arrays theme.
This my cration and what is the program in it:

```
    <?PHP
 out("test starts");
 $people[] = array (
            "name" => "Brook",
            "age" => "42"
                 );
 $people[] = array (
            "name" => "Peter",
            "age" => "18"
                 );

 foreach($people as $person)
  out($person=>["name"] . " - " . $person=>["age"]);

/*
 I wanna this:
 Brook - 42
 Peter - 18

*/

 var_dump($people);
 out("test ends");


 function out($what) {
  echo $what . "<br>\n";
 }
?>
```

The var_dump is show me the array creation is good but the trouble is at foreach.

Comment: `out($person["name"] . " - " . $person["age"]);`... you don't use the `=>` here

Comment: Use this `out($person["name"] . " - " . $person["age"]);` instead.

Comment: as you are still learning, it would be helpful for you to turn the PHP errors on.

Comment: This is a result, I erased the => operator from my code and it do what I want.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is most probably in this:
`out($person=>["name"] . " - " . $person=>["age"]);`

instead use `out($person["name"] . " - " . $person["age"]);`

Answer (score 0):

Assigning:

```
$name = array("key1" => value1,
"key2" => value2);
```

Accessing:

```
echo $name["key1"];
echo $name["key2"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove `=>`. To access array properties you need to use square brackets `$person["name"]` (for objects use `->`).

I found a very detailed answer about this topic here:
[How can I access an array/object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680938/how-can-i-access-an-array-object)