# How to get the value from a specific key in an array?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have the following array:

```
Array (
    [result] => Array (
        [id] => 58fba3ebf4
        [type] => A
        [name] => ser.domain.com
        [content] => 192.168.100.1
        [proxiable] => 
        [proxied] => 
        [ttl] => 1 
        [priority] => 10 
        [locked] => 
        [zone_id] => eb0d86828e3ac837c 
        [zone_name] => domain.com 
        [modified_on] => 2018-07-06T06:37:14.069598Z
        [created_on] => 2018-07-06T06:37:14.069598Z
        [meta] => Array (
            [auto_added] => 
            [managed_by_apps] => 
            [managed_by_argo_tunnel] => 
        )
    )
    [success] => 1
    [errors] => Array ( )
    [messages] => Array ( )
)
```

How can I just get the value from `id`?

Comment: What have you tried? Maybe `$arrays['result']['id']`? A good [read](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access an array/object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680938/how-can-i-access-an-array-object)

Comment: @AramGrigoryan Please avoid posting solutions as comments.  Posting solutions as comments does several bad things to StackOverflow including 1. Question Abandonment by the OP, 2. Bad page content -- whereby future researchers have to look in multiple sections of the page to find "solutions".

Comment: @hungrykoala Please avoid posting solutions as comments.  Posting solutions as comments does several bad things to StackOverflow including 1. Question Abandonment by the OP, 2. Bad page content -- whereby future researchers have to look in multiple sections of the page to find "solutions".

Comment: @KENNETH I have downvoted because the downvote hint-text says: "_This question does not shows any research effort_"

Comment: I thought this would be closed as this is a question that should be common knowledge. I'm sure a duplicate of this exists in SO as well. I mean a lot of dupes.

Comment: I agree, but you didn't voted to close, right?

Comment: I was going to but it slipped my mind. I even forgot I commented here. I'll remember to flag after commenting next time.

Answer (score 0):

```
$data =json_decode($response);

  $id = $data->result->id;
```

Assuming your payload from the request was $response.

Comment: Code-only answer are low-value on StackOverflow.  Everytime you post an answer, do so with the intent to educate the OP and thousands of future researchers who may not know how your solution works or why it is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution

//  $result_array() is your reponse from curl PHP

$data  = $result_array();

$id = $data['result']['id'];

Comment: Code-only answer are low-value on StackOverflow.  Everytime you post an answer, do so with the intent to educate the OP and thousands of future researchers who may not know how your solution works or why it is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You already have a multi-dimensional array so just try like this

```
echo $arrays['result']['id']; // this will return id
echo $arrays['result']['type']; // this will return type
```

Comment: this is a no attempt, mega-duplicate, please support my closure