# Parsing php array with many elements and objects

Tags: php, arrays, parsing

I am new to php arrays and struggling to get my head around how to parse data from them. I have had a look at [How can I access an array/object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680938/how-can-i-access-an-array-object)

but is just beyond my grasp. Need an example to understand. So i have this array in a $result variable

```
Array
(
    [response] => Array
        (
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [fieldData] => Array
                                (
                                    [CURRENT_PRIVILEGESET] => FM Data API
                                )
                            [portalData] => Array
                                (
                                )
                            [recordId] => 1
                            [modId] => 0
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [fieldData] => Array
                                (
                                    [CURRENT_PRIVILEGESET] => FM Data API
                                )
                            [portalData] => Array
                                (
                                )
                            [recordId] => 2
                            [modId] => 0
                        )
                )
        )
    [messages] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [code] => 0
                    [message] => OK
                )
        )
)
```

How do i get the value for [CURRENT_PRIVILEGESET]? I have tried the below but i think i have misunderstood something. Thanks all for your patience while i try to get to grips with this.

```
$privilege = $result["response"]['data'][0]->fielddata["CURRENT_PRIVILEGESET"];
```

Comment: Why `->fielddata`?  Should be `['fieldData']` it's an array and keys are case sensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no object in your example. With `->` you are referring to an object. These are all arrays, so you can just go on with the keys:

```
$privilege = $result["response"]['data'][0]["fieldData"]["CURRENT_PRIVILEGESET"];
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$result['response']['data'][0]['fieldData']['CURRENT_PRIVILEGESET'];
```

You've used an object notation of `->` but you're working with arrays the whole way down, not objects.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you want to traverse(move through) an object, you do that using the arrow(`->`) notation whereas for arrays, you do that by accessing the index(`[x]`) notation where `x` could either be an `int` e.g `[1]` or a `string` e.g `['data']`.

I am assuming you know what classes, objects as well as arrays are. 
Let's assume we have a `class` called `Test` and an `object` of `Test` class called `$testObj`, whenever we do `var_dump($testobj)`, from top down, you would see something like this:

```
object(Test)[1]
public 'feeling' => string 'Love' (length=4)
public 'inverse' => string 'hate' (length=4)
```

This simply means that the `object` we are var_dumping belongs to the `Test` class and we can access the `feeling` property of `$testObj` like so:
    `$testObj->feeling`;

This structure is not very different for `arrays`. If we have an `array` called `$testArr` and do a `var_dump($testArr)`, we would see:

```
array (size=2)
  'feeling' => string 'love' (length=4)
  'inverse' => string 'hate' (length=4)
  3 => int 300
```

Again, we see that, the type is stated; in this case `Array`. We can access some of the indexes like so:
    $testArr['feeling']    //Outputs love
    $testArr[3]            //Outputs 300

For your use case, you can traverse down to `CURRENT_PRIVILEGESET` like so:

```
$privilege = $result["response"]['data'][0]["fieldData"]["CURRENT_PRIVILEGESET"];
```

Checkout these resources for more info.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.object.php
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php