# How can I access each value from an array?

Tags: php, json, database, laravel, object

This is the array

```
$resultData2 = array ( 
    0 => array ( 
        "email" => "abcd@gmail.com", 
        "fname" => "sachin" 
    ) 
);
```

How can I access each value such as `email`, `fname`?

I am trying to access it like this :

```
echo $resultData2[0]->email;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try like this$resultData2[0]['email'] as there is no object to access

Comment: That is an array, isn't it? -> is used on objects. $resultData2[0]['email']

Comment: Please see this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access an array/object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680938/how-can-i-access-an-array-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using foreach loop.

```
foreach($resultData2 as $resultData)
{
    echo $resultData['email'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an array :

```
$resultData2 = array(
    0 => array(
        "email" => "abcd@gmail.com",
        "fname" => "sachin"
    )
);
```

You are doing `echo $resultData2[0]->email;`, but this is the syntax if `$resultData2[0]` was a object.

With array, use `echo $resultData2[0]['email'];`

Answer (score 0):

```
    $email = array_column( $array,'email');
    $fname = array_column($array,'fname');
```