# How to get value intro array/ array

Tags: php, arrays

I happen to be unable to retrieve the value that is coming out of the foreach, as you can see in var_dump.

I need to get the value "string 'http://www.selperbrasil.org.br/cursos/ead/geobia/"

my code where:

```
var_dump($news_item->evento_url);
array (size=1)
  'und' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          'value' => string 'http://www.selperbrasil.org.br/cursos/ead/geobia/' (length=49)
          'format' => null
          'safe_value' => string 'http://www.selperbrasil.org.br/cursos/ead/geobia/' (length=49)
```

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/q/30680938/3933332

Comment: `$news_item->evento_url['und'][0]['value']`