# How to get elements from this array without using a loop in php?

Tags: php, arrays

I think that I'm having a syntax issue here. I have an array that, when I dump and die it, looks like this:

```
^ array:1 [
    0 => array:3 [
      "something" => "-12"
      "somethingElse" => "2"
      "somethingThird" => "2"
    ]
  ]
```

I am having a hard time returning the actual items in the array inside this array. I've tried:

```
$myArray->something;
$myArray->0;
$myArray[0]->something;
$myArray[0]['something'];
$myArray['something'];
```

and i keep getting undefined offset errors. I think i'm not understanding the structure of this array of arrays. Can anyone help? Thank you!

EDIT:
print_r of the array:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [something] => -12 [somethingElse] => 2 [somethingThird] => 2 ) )
```

Comment: `$myarray[0]['something']` you are using Object notation and you have an array not an object

Comment: Arrow syntax only works on objects.

Comment: Hmmm thank you, when I try `myarray[0]['something']` I get an error that says "undefined offset 0"! any idea why?

Comment: Because offset __does not exist__ obviously.

Comment: Multi-dimensional arrays are such type of arrays which stores an another array at each index instead of single element. That is, an array of arrays. In php, you can access the array element at `nth` index as `$array['n']`;

Comment: put real array, as you have in code, an then what result you need

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30681087/4050077

Comment: @OtarShavadze the array above is the exact array I get when i do a dump and die. It's an array with another array pushed into it. There's only one array within the parent array at the moment. I don't understand how the offset 0 doesn't exist if there is one array within my array @u_mulder?

Comment: Please show us a `print_r($your_array);`

Comment: Fiddle __works__ https://3v4l.org/hgTVj What is real data taht you use - noone has no idea.

Comment: @RiggsFolly added print_r to post above

Comment: Then I dont understand why code in my first comment does not work

Comment: Unless there are some odd invisible characters in there, so sorry, can you show us a `var_dump($myarray);` please

Answer (score 0):

You are getting array data the wrong way. Get data like `$myArray[0]['something']` way.

```
// this is wrong way 
$myArray->something;
$myArray->0;

// right way to getting array
echo "something: " . $myArray[0]['something'] . PHP_EOL;
echo "somethingElse: " . $myArray[0]['somethingElse'] . PHP_EOL;
echo "somethingThird: " . $myArray[0]['somethingThird'] . PHP_EOL;
```

**=> Output**

```
something: -12
somethingElse: 2
somethingThird: 2
```