# get an array by position instead of key

Tags: php, arrays

I just want to return an array value of an array by knowing it's position but not the key.

```
array(
    [807]=> array(
       [0] => "test",
       [1] => "test2"
    ),
    [808]=> array(
       [0] => "test",
       [1] => "test2"
    ),
    [809]=> array(
       [0] => "test",
       [1] => "test2"
    ),
    [810]=> array(
       [0] => "test",
       [1] => "test2"
    )
)
```

Let's say i've got the exact positions i want to check:
How do i access array[2] to return array with key 809?

Note: array keys wont be all the time succesive.

Thank you

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680938/how-can-i-access-an-array-object

Comment: [array_​keys](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) will return a list of ... array keys

Answer (score 1):

Nvm!
I found a way by doing this:

```
$original_keys = array_keys($original_array);
$search_KEY = $original_keys[$key];
```

Where `$key` is known as position of the original array. This would return me the exact array key-value pair by using `$original_array[$search_KEY]`

Comment: This duplicate question didn't need to be answered to be resolved.