# Accesing request file from array in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, request, laravel-8

i want access file i upload from client side using an array in php.

this is my request

```
{
    "first_name": "name",
    "last_name": "test",
    "religion": "islam",
    "date_of_birth": "2022-12-01",
    "phone": "213123123",
    "gender": "male",
    "identity_cards": [
        {
            "document_category_id": "1",
            "number": "1283712",
            "exp_date": "2020-11-20",
            "image": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

how can i possible to access the images?

i try some method like

```
$request->file('identity_cards[0][image]');
```

but doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will work.

```
$request->file('identity_cards.0.image');
```

Answer (score -1):

Object and array use different operators. For your case, you can use this

```
$request->file('identity_cards[0]->image');
```

So if your data like this:

```php
"identity_cards": [
  {
            "document_category_id": "1",
            "number": "1283712",
            "exp_date": "2020-11-20",
            "image": {
                url: "blablabla.com"
            }
  }
```

How to access url? just modify it.

```php
$request->file('identity_cards[0]->image->url');
```

[Explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680938/how-can-i-access-an-array-object)

Comment: it's fail, and i try to get file type return null