# php echo each item in different arrays from json_decode

Tags: php, arrays, json, get

I can't get php to list each item from the arrays with

```
foreach($decodedData->data->array as $values)
    {
         echo $values->title . "\n";
```

While I'm trying it to list as such (I know my code isn't setup to list each variable, but I cant even list the title with my current code):
*Title 1, ID, URL-Title 2, ID, URL-Title 3, ID, URL*

$decodedData array:

```
array(2) {
  ["data"]=>
  array(10) {
    [0]=>
    array(1) {
      ["node"]=>
      array(3) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(20)
        ["title"]=>
        string(6) "title"
        ["main_picture"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["medium"]=>
          string(57) "url"
          ["large"]=>
          string(58) "url"
        }
      }
    }
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      ["node"]=>
      array(3) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(42249)
        ["title"]=>
        string(15) "title"
        ["main_picture"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["medium"]=>
          string(60) "url"
          ["large"]=>
          string(61) "url"
        }
      }
    }
    [2]=>
    array(1) {
      ["node"]=>
      array(3) {
        ["id"]=>
        int(44511)
        ["title"]=>
        string(12) "title"
        ["main_picture"]=>
        array(2) {
          ["medium"]=>
          string(60) "url"
          ["large"]=>
          string(61) "url"
        }
      }
    }
```

The relevant code:

```
    // Decoding JSON data
    $decodedData =
        json_decode($result, true);
    // Decoded form
    var_dump($decodedData);
    foreach($decodedData->data->array as $values)
    {
         echo $values->title . "\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of `json_decode($json, $associative)` controls whether you will get an object (if set to FALSE) or an associative array (if set to TRUE).

from the PHP docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

> *associative*
> When true, JSON objects will be returned as associative arrays; when false, JSON objects will be returned as objects. When
> null, JSON objects will be returned as associative arrays or objects
> depending on whether JSON_OBJECT_AS_ARRAY is set in the flags.*

So you should either pass FALSE to the second parameter to receive a list of objects or to update your code to work with a regular array:

```
foreach($decodedData['data'] as $values) {
    echo $values['node']['title'] . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`$decodedData->data` doesn't have a property called "array" so `->array` makes no sense. The `data` item is itself an array, so you can loop through that.

Also there are no objects here at all so there should be no attempts to access object properties using `->`. You have decoded the JSON in associative array format (by using `true` as the second argument to [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)).

And if you look at the data structure more closely, you'll also see that "title" is actually under another layer with a key named "node".

So I expect that

```
foreach ($decodedData["data"] as $item) { 
  echo $item["node"]["title"] . "\n";
}
```

should do the trick.

Background reading: [How to extract and access data from JSON with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29308898/how-to-extract-and-access-data-from-json-with-php) and [How can I access an array/object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680938/how-can-i-access-an-array-object)