# How to add or display dynamic array variables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, dynamic-programming

I am converting my multi dimensional post variables to dynamic variables as below:

```
foreach($_POST as $k => $v){
   ${$k} = $v;
}
```

So my new array looks like this:

```
Array(
   [name] => Joe
   [surname] => Blogs
   [study] => Array
        (
            [0] => English
            [1] => IT
        )
   [school] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Some School Name
                    [1] => 03/09/2015
                    [2] => Present
                )    
        )
)
```

So if I want to get the school name, this code will work:

```
echo $school[0][0];
```

However, I am struggling to use this variable in an sql statement like below:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (name, surname, subject_1, subject_2, school1_name, school1_datefrom, school1_dateto) VALUES ('$name', '$surname', '$subject[0]', '$subject[1]', '$school[0][0]', '$school[0][1]', '$school[0][2]', '$school[0][3]')";

echo $sql;
```

All variables that are not an array or single level array like `study` are getting displayed fine but the school variables like `$school[0][0]` are displaying as 'Array[0]', 'Array[1]'.........
Why is it doing this and is there away I can get those variables to display correctly?

Answer (score 2):

If you wrap the arrayed values in `{}` then it should work as you have it. I cannot remember the reasoning behind this but try it.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (name, surname, subject_1, subject_2, 
                           school1_name, school1_datefrom, 
                           school1_dateto) 
              VALUES ('$name', '$surname', '{$subject[0]}', 
                      '{$subject[1]}', '{$school[0][0]}',
                       '{$school[0][1]', '{$school[0][2]}', 
                       '{$school[0][3]}')";
```

I remember now is called Complex (curly) syntax

Not because the syntax is complex, but because it allows for the use of complex expressions.

Comment: thank you, that has worked. i think for simplicity, i will wrap each variable in a curly bracket including the variables that are not an array and just remember this syntax as a rule when i come to add variables in an sql query

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the variable in **{}**, It should work. Curly braces are used to explicitly specify the end of a variable name.

Quickly...

```
$number = 4;
print "You have the {$number}th edition book";
//output: "You have the 4th edition book";
```

Wihtout curly braces PHP try to find a variable named $numberth, that not exist!

hope this helps.

[Ref.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147937/php-curly-brace-syntax-for-member-variable)

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (name, surname, subject_1, subject_2, school1_name, school1_datefrom, school1_dateto) VALUES ('$name', '$surname', '$subject[0]', '$subject[1]', '$school[0][0]', '$school[0][1]', '$school[0][2]', '$school[0][3]')";
```

with

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (name, surname, subject_1, subject_2, school1_name, school1_datefrom, school1_dateto) VALUES ('$name', '$surname', '{$subject[0]}', '{$subject[1]}', '{$school[0][0]}', '{$school[0][1]}', '{$school[0][2]}', '{$school[0][3]}')";
```