# What does brackets like {variable}(variable|array) statement means in php?

Tags: php, syntax, brackets, curly-braces

I couldn't google this one. The question;

```
public function processAPI() {
    if (method_exists($this, $this->endpoint)) {
        return $this->_response($this->{$this->endpoint}($this->args));
    }
    return $this->_response("No Endpoint: $this->endpoint", 404);
}
```

Consider `$endpoint` is a variable and `$args` is an array of a class. We want to pass the variable `$this->{$this->endpoint}($this->args)` to `_response()` method. What does `{$this->endpoint}($this->args)` means in php syntax?

The link of full definition of code: http://coreymaynard.com/blog/creating-a-restful-api-with-php/

Comment: If this isn't already a duplicate, it should be added to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php

Comment: This is due to using [variable variables](https://secure.php.net/manual/language.variables.variable.php) - or in this case variable method names. But as far as I know considered bad practice, you can use [`call_user_func()`](https://secure.php.net/call_user_func) instead

Comment: @zzzzBov This is not covered in the linked question, or am I just unable to find it there?

Comment: @kingkero, I didn't see it covered in the question I linked, but there may be alternative questions that this is a duplicate of

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP curly brace syntax for member variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147937/php-curly-brace-syntax-for-member-variable)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$this->_response($this->{$this->endpoint}($this->args));
```

Divide and conquer:

```
$this->_response()
```

Means calling the method _response() of the current object with the argument

```
$this->{$this->endpoint}($this->args)
```

The curly braces are explained here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

> Any scalar variable, array element or object property with a string
>   representation can be included via this syntax. Simply write the
>   expression the same way as it would appear outside the string, and
>   then wrap it in { and }. Since { can not be escaped, this syntax will
>   only be recognised when the $ immediately follows the {. Use {\$ to
>   get a literal {$.

Therefore {$this->endpoint} evaluates to a string which was previously set as endpoint property of the current object.

```
$this->endpointproperty($this->args)
```

There must be a method endpoint property in the current object which accepts one argument. This Argument is also a property of this object:

```
$this->args
```

Comment: It means I can call the method that its name is inside my $endpoint variable. If api call is like ".../cars/mercedes/2015", it means I have a cars() method and I'm passing it the ['mercedes,'2015'] array. omg. Thanks.