# How to get values from xml which has "@" at the beginning of the tag name?

Tags: php, xml

I'm trying to get values from a XML file, but I have a problem. One of tag name starts with "@". So I'm getting an error on that.

This is my xml

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#537 (1) { ["urun"]=> array(5225) { [0]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#547 (1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(7) { ["id"]=> string(4) "2972" ["secenekid"]=> string(1) "4" ["grup"]=> string(4) "YAŞ" ["ozellik"]=> string(1) "1" ["fiyat"]=> string(1) "0" ["agirlik"]=> string(1) "0" ["Stok"]=> string(1) "0" } } [1]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#548 (1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(7) { ["id"]=> string(4) "2972" ["secenekid"]=> string(1) "5" ["grup"]=> string(4) "YAŞ" ["ozellik"]=> string(1) "2" ["fiyat"]=> string(1) "0" ["agirlik"]=> string(1) "0" ["Stok"]=> string(1) "0" } }
```

I'm trying to get like that.

```
$url = "http://xx.com";
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

foreach($xml->urun->@attributes as $val) {
echo $val->id; 
}
```

and this is the error what I see

```
syntax error, unexpected '@', expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$'
```

so what should I do know for to solve that?

Thanks.

Comment: `foreach($xml->urun->attributes() as $key  => $val)`

Comment: If your document really has tag names beginning with `@`, then it's not XML.

Comment: Don't mistake SimpleXMLs debug output for the actual data - here are big differences.

Answer (score 0):

The curly braces syntax can be used to access such properties:

```
$xml->urun->{'@attributes'}
```

See [PHP curly brace syntax for member variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147937/php-curly-brace-syntax-for-member-variable)

In this case you could also use `$xml->urun->attributes()`, see [Accessing @attribute from SimpleXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1652128/accessing-attribute-from-simplexml)

Answer (score -3):

I find it easiest to convert xml to arrays via JSON encode/decode because array keys can contain '@' with no problem and arrays are easy to traverse:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($url);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$data = json_decode($json,true);
```

Now you have an array.  Use `print_r` to see its shape on screen.  To access attributes you would do:

```
echo $data['@attributes']['Name']
```

Comment: Doing all this encoding and decoding just to get a slightly different access syntax seems like an overkill to me.

Comment: @ShiraNai7 actually I agree with you :-)  It would be overkill if it were just for that purpose. I gave my reasons including `arrays are easy to traverse`. I just didn't elaborate so since you probably downvoted, let me elaborate a bit:  By doing it this way, I can perform arithmetic functions on the data, I can `array_map`, `array_filter`, `array_merge`...  I can add it to other arrays, I can do `array_intersect` to quickly compare to other xml data...  PHP is just a beast with arrays so...

Comment: It might be useful if a complete conversion to a multidimensional array is needed but it still feels dirty :)

Comment: Bad Idea, SimpleXML implements many interfaces like ArrayAccess, Traversable and Magic Methods. You will actually loose both information and ease of access. Check `SimpleXMLElement::xpath()` for example.