# how to call this kind of php object

Tags: php

hi can you please solve this problem

I have PHP object in from mailgun, now i want to echo user-varibles from this object but there something wrong

[image: please check images this is array image i get]

```
    <?php foreach ($mailresult->http_response_body->items as $key => $value): ?>
        <?= $value->user-varibles->order_id ?>  /**i want to echo this order_id **/
    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: `$mailresult->http_response_body->items[$key]->order_id` or just `$value->order_id`? Can you give a minimum reproducable example?

Comment: What kind of error do you get when you're trying to access the variable?

Comment: `$value->{'user-variables'}->order_id`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP curly brace syntax for member variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147937/php-curly-brace-syntax-for-member-variable)